# How to make JSON loads faster with large data (on HTTP or WebPage)

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

.  Requesting the page(on HTTP or WebPage), it is very slow or even crash unless i load my JSON with fewer data. I really need to solve this since sooner or later i will be using large amount of data frequently. Here are my JSON data. --->>>
[image: Click here to JSON treeview]

Notes: 
 1. The JSON loads only String and Integer. 
 2. I used to view my JSON in JSONView more like treeview using plugin
    from GoogleChrome.

I am using angular and nodejs. tq

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: Assuming bandwidth really is the limiting factor here, there really isn't any solution other than being more selective about what data you request from the server. Strip out any data you don't actually need, do more preprocessing on the server, load data incrementally where possible, etc.

Comment: @StefansArya on HTTP or WebPage screen perhaps.

Comment: @DanielBeck Unfortunately, i cannot strip out any data. That is the possible data need to be use..

Comment: @Alburkerk thank you. i shouldve write that HTTP earlier.

Comment: @FaridFauzi :D Actually my ironic answer meant : "We need more informations". If there was a way to make all http request faster, it would be in the node package in the first place. You need to optimize your data structure to remove any redundancy and maybe try make multiple http request and adapt your UI in the Front-End so the user won't notice that (kinda smart pagination)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by large amount of data ? What kind of data is it ? Images ? Video ? Or only string ? I know you said it was a json but you can store image as a byte array in a json

Comment: If there is a large amount of data, maybe you can use paging and display one page at a time and fetch data for only that page. If you have to get all the data at once and there is no other option, you can try to enable compression from the server so that the data is compressed.

Comment: Remove the "I" as you can use Object.keys() to get key name

Comment: Do you need that much precision on the float ?

Comment: I am not sure where and how in UI/Web page you are going to bind the data..But if you are fetching a json list with 1000 elements and going to show 10 elements at one point of time, it is better to use pagination or something like that...chunk up your json based on the amount of data you show up on UI

Comment: It would be better to use mysql if you want to process a larger data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A quick resume of all the things that comes to my mind :**

I had a similar issue once. My solutions may make the UI change.

1. **Pagination**

I doubt you can display that much data at one time, so the strategy should be divising your data in small amounts and then only load more when the client ask for it.

This way, the whole data is no longer stored in RAM as it is currently. This is how forums works (only 20 topics at a time).

*Just imagine if StackOverflow make you load the whole historic of questions in the main page, how much GB would your navigator need just for that ?*

You can use pagination in a classic way (button with page number, like google), or in an infinite scroll way, as you want.

For that you need to adapt your api and keep track of the index of the pages you already loaded at every moment in your Front. There are plenty of examples in AngularJS.

2. **Only show the beginning of the data**

When you look at Facebook comments, you may have a "show more" button. In their case, maybe it's to not break the UI, but it can also be used to not overload data.

You can display only the main lines of your datae (titles or somewhat) and add a button so the user can load more details if they want.

In your data model, the cost seems to be on the second level of "C". Just load data untill this second level, and download the remaining part (**for this object**) only if the user asks for.

Once again, no need to overload, your client's RAM will be thankfull, and your client's mobile 3G too.

3. **Optimize your data stucture**

*If this is still not enough :*

- As [StefanArya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6563200/stefansarya) said in comment, indeed remove the "I" attribute, which is redundant with the JSON key.

> Remove the "I" as you can use Object.keys() to get key name.

- You also may don't need that much precision on your floats.

If I see any other ideas, I'll edit this post later.